# Recursively building a list of lists

Tags: scala

The following code compiles as long as the return type of the recursive call is Any, but obviously I'm doing something wrong because it should not have to be Any.

```
  case class Group(
    id: Long = -1,
    parentId: Long = -1,
    name: String = "")

  def makeTree(groupId: Long, groups: List[Group]) = {
    def getAllChildren(gid: Long): Any = {
      def children = for {
        g <- groups; if g.parentId == gid
      } yield g

      if (children.isEmpty) List()
      else {
        children map { x =>
          getAllChildren(x.id)
        }
      }
    }
    getAllChildren(groupId)
  }                                               
  val groups = List(Group(1, 0, "A"), 
                    Group(2, 1, "B"), 
                    Group(3, 1, "C"), 
                    Group(4, 2, "D"))

  makeTree(1, groups)
  //Results in: Any = List(List(List()), List())
  }
```

If I change the signature of getAllChildren to:

```
def getAllChildren(gid: Long): List[Group]
```

then I get an error:

```
type mismatch;  found   : List[List[Group]]  required: List[Group]
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really speaking scala, but it looks like, for some id, you collect the groups with that id, and then replace each group with a list of it's children, and so on.

Specifically, here:

```
  if (children.isEmpty) List()
  else {
    children map { x =>
      getAllChildren(x.id)
     }
  }
```

Indeed, here is the root of your error: Your algorithm allows for infinite recursion, and each recursion adds another `List[...]` around your return type. But you can't have a type with dynamic depth.

For example, if you try to fix this by giving type `List[List[Group]]`, it will complain that it found `List[List[List[Group]]]`, and so on, until you give up.

This is the way typecheckers tell us that we're about to program a *potentially* infinite recursion. You may have assumed the invariant that your hierarchy can't involve loops, yet this is not reflected in the types. In fact, it is not hard to construct an example where two groups are each others parents. In that case, your program will produce an ever deeper nesting list until it terminates due to lack of memory.

Note that you can't fix your code simply by using flatMap instead of map: the reason being that getAllChildren never ever produces a list with Group elements. It either returns an empty list, or, a flattened list of empty lists, that is, an empty list. Hence, if it should return at all, it would return an empty list in the flatmap version.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation Ingo. I see now why I always get empty lists. Chirlo's example does return content, but unfortunately flatMap causes the structure of the parent child relationships to be lost. I'm trying to build a tree. I suppose I can fix this by creating my own collection type, but I was hoping for a simple fix to my current code. Just to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the call to `children map ...` for `children flatMap ...`, otherwise you're not returning a `List[Group]` but potentially a `List[List[.....]]` like @Ingo suggests. `flatMap` will map each element to a `List` and then flatten all lists to create just one `List[Group]` containing all children.

**EDIT**: As @Ingo points out, even if `flatMap` would solve the typing problem, your function still doesn't work, since you always return an empty List. You should go for

```
children flatMap { x => x :: getAllChildren(x.id, acc) }
```

to prepend the child to the child's children.

Comment: Note that this wont work as it stands. `getAllChildren` never produces a list that actually contains `Group` elements. Think about it.

Comment: Right, he always returns an empty `List`. I added a solution to the answer

Comment: Yep, looks better. However, we should also have detection of cycles in the input to prevent infinite loops. Consider `groups = List(Group(1,2,"A"), Group(2,3,"B"), Group(3,1,"C"))`

Comment: Thank you very much Chirlo. Unfortunately this flattens the whole structure. My broken version returns empty lists, but the structure stays in tact: List(List(List()), List()). Using flatMap unfortunately causes the structure to disappear:List(Group(2,1,B), Group(4,2,D), Group(3,1,C)). I am trying to represent the tree of parents with their children as lists. Thanks for the great help so far.

Comment: Ok, but then returning `List[Group]` doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work if you flatten the list returned on `children map` like this:

```
def makeTree(groupId: Long, groups: List[Group]) = {
  def getAllChildren(gid: Long): List[Group] = {
    def children = for {
      g <- groups; if g.parentId == gid
    } yield g

    if (children.isEmpty) List()
    else {
      val listList = children map { x =>
        x :: getAllChildren(x.id)
      }

      listList.flatten
    }
  }
  getAllChildren(groupId)
}
```

The reason this is happening is that you are taking a List[Group] and mapping it over a function that also returns a `List[Group]`, thus resulting in a `List[List[Group]]`.  Simply flattening that List will produce the desired result.

Comment: "Simply flattening that List will produce the desired result." - no, it won't, unless the empty list is the desired result. And when the data introduce cycles, it'll not even terminate.